# Client Request Interrupted in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having a really strange problem with Heroku right now.

I can freely browse the website. But some operations are giving me the following error:

```
sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/api/upload/image/"
```

Based on these, I guess `GET` operations are working fine(e.g. browsing the pages), but `POST` operations are not(e.g. uploading images)

P.S. I am using Django

So, I thought it was my latest `commit` doing this. But even after I rolled back to yesterday's state when it was working, it is giving the same result.

Is this an internal Heroku problem and I should just wait? or is it me doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is with my Internet Service Provider. They were doing some prophylactic work and external services such as Heroku were out of reach.

The solution was using a Tor browser until ISP get things done.

Comment: I think the solution put by @gabriel Grant down there is the right, and more general solution. Apparently Heroku has a well known problem when dealing with file uploads and the solution to this is mentioned in the guides

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be running into Heroku's request timeout limit: they [automatically cut off requests after 30 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)

I've usually run into this when processing file uploads; [Heroku's official recommendation is to upload files directly to S3 instead.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#uploading-large-files)

Comment: The strange thing is, it is not only with uploading. The same thing is happening when I try to edit and save something in django admin. Pulling my hair out..aghhh